# Long URLs make UIApplication openURL: fail on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiapplication, openurl

I'm scratching my head on this one:

I've got two apps, and pass images between the two by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appURL];`. Images are base64-encoded. It worked great until now.

Now, in iOS 9, it works only with small-medium images, and silently fails otherwise. On lower hardware like iPhone 5, it works only with tiny images.

It looks like a memory issue, but I haven't read anything about a change in iOS 9 that would trigger this. Does anybody know this problem (and ideally have a solution)?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've added your URL schemes to your .plist file as an entry:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>YOUR_URL_SCHEME</string>
</array>
```

Read more here about changes in iOS 9

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703

Comment: This entry only fixes calls to `canOpenURL:`, not `openURL:`.

Comment: Actually, in earlier betas of iOS 9, it did affect both: https://openradar.appspot.com/21320635 :)